# How do I configure Windows 10 to accept multiple USB game controllers?

Tags: windows, usb, game-controller

I have purchased several USB game controllers and wish to use at least 2 of them simultaneously to play a game with friends.  The game itself supports up to 4 controllers and I have have no trouble with this if I use a game controller adapter with multiple input ports and a single USB connection to the PC.

Unfortunately I do not own such an adapter for the controllers I want to use, so I attempted to use the individual controllers on their own USB ports.  The first one connects and operates perfectly and connecting the second results in a message that windows is unable to load the driver/run the hardware.  If I reverse the order of connecting the devices the former second controller works perfectly and the former first controller now generates the error, thus I don't suspect a hardware failure of either controller.

Is there a particular technique for connecting multiple independent USB game controllers under Windows 10 that anyone can recommend?

Comment: Without knowing what controllers are you attempting to use this will be difficult to answer.  You should have no problem with wired Xbox 360 and Xbox One controllers if you are using Windows 10.  Multiple wireless Xbox controllers, is more problematic, but not possible.

Comment: 2 identical USB wired NES controllers.

Comment: "if I use a game controller adapter with multiple input ports" - What exactly do you mean by this statement?

Comment: The adapter looks like a game controller hub.  I do not own one for NES controllers ie: https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=How_to_use_the_Official_GameCube_Controller_Adapter_for_Wii_U_in_Dolphin

Comment: Could be a problem with the usb port. Does a controller work if you just use one and try it in every usb port?

Comment: @LPChip Yes the controllers work fine in any port if used one at a time.

Comment: Could you try connecting three of them (assuming you have that many of the identical controllers) and see if you get two working?

Comment: I have bad news.  You are not going to be able to use multiple controllers without that adapter.

Comment: @Ramhound If you can expand that comment out a bit and post it as an answer I will accept it.